# Javascript innerWidth isn't working

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var x = window.innerWidth;
if (window.innerWidth<500){
function myFunction() {
    var node = document.getElementById("myList2").firstChild;
    document.getElementById("myList1").appendChild(node);
}}
var myVar = setInterval(myFunction, 1000);    

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = x;
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<ul id="myList1"><li>Coffee</li><li>Tea</li></ul>
<ul id="myList2"><li>Water</li><li>Milk</li></ul>
<p id="test"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

My width is 1366px but the above code executes and adds the li to myList1. Any help will be appreciated. May be it is a newbie question but I'm new to coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should move your conditional in the function:

```js
var x = window.innerWidth;
function myFunction() {
    if ( x < 500 ) {
        var node = document.getElementById("myList2").firstChild;
        document.getElementById("myList1").appendChild(node);
    }
}
var myVar = setInterval(myFunction, 1000);    
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = x;
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<ul id="myList1"><li>Coffee</li><li>Tea</li></ul>
<ul id="myList2"><li>Water</li><li>Milk</li></ul>
<p id="test"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: whats the difference between your code and that of the one asked but +Jahanzaib Asgher. if you answer to this question then my knowledge will surely expand.

Comment: @Annisaini , in the OP's code, the interval is executing `myFunction` no matter what the window width is (there is no conditional check). In my code, the function is also being executed on an interval, but the conditional check is happening every time, since the conditional is contained in the function itself.

Comment: thanks a lot. I think function can't be used inside condition.

Answer (score 1):

you can also check before invocation:

```js
var x = window.innerWidth;

function myFunction() {
    var node = document.getElementById("myList2").firstChild;
    document.getElementById("myList1").appendChild(node);
    
  
}

if (window.innerWidth < 500) {
    var myVar = setInterval(myFunction, 1000);
}


document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = x;
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <ul id="myList1">
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="myList2">
    <li>Water</li>
    <li>Milk</li>
  </ul>
  <p id="test"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

`setInterval` in this case is not an ideal solution because it will keep on calling the function until there will be no `var node` and then you'll get errors every time the function is called.